# using jQuery with Jekyll site hosted on Github pages

Tags: jquery, github, jekyll

I have a simpled Jekyll blog hosted on github pages and I have included jQuery and a tablesorter plugin but come across error and to all my knowledge this error is caused by not having jQuery loaded in the correct order. my image below shows the code is in the right order.. so my question is simply is it being stopped by Github itself somehow?

and if so how?

[image: my code of include scripts]

edit: for completion/clarity here is the exact code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javscript" src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" ></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { 
 if(jQuery("table.tablesorter").length > 0)
   {  
    $.tablesorter.defaults.widgets = ['zebra']; }
   }
 );
```

Comment: If you visit http://your.jekyll.site/js/jquery.min.js is the file really served?

Comment: it is yes, as it the tablesorter plugin, even putting the third script into an external file it is still called. but same error.

Comment: Typo: `type="text/javscript"` should be `type="text/javascript"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turns out it's not a jekyll or github issue having copied files to my own server. it seems to be an issue with my plugins and jQuery 2.0.0, going back to 1.9.0 works.

ugh